# How to find out which airlines have a MITA?

Tags: airlines

While researching Air Passes, I recently found out that there is something called a MITA which stands for *Multilateral Interline Traffic Agreement*.

According to the rules for the Gol Brazil Air Pass for example, one needs to enter Brazil on either one of the partner airlines (Air France, KLM, Delta) or *travel on flights operated and ticketed by any airline with which GOL (G3) has a mita agreement*.

**How does one find out which airlines have a MITA agreement then?**

Bonus points for also explaining what is a MITA and why it matters.

Comment: Isn't this more suited for Aviation.se?

Comment: @motoDrizzt - Don't think so. It has to do with the travel agreements for ticketing not the functioning or aircraft and related infrastructure.

Comment: @motoDrizzt Itai is right. This question would be off-topic at Aviation. Interline agreements are focused much more on the passenger aspects of commercial aviation, which are off-topic at Aviation SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to IATA, the [Multilateral Interline Traffic Agreements (MITA)](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/workgroups/Pages/mita.aspx) is:

> an agreement whereby passengers and cargo use a standard traffic
>   document (i.e. passenger ticket or air waybill) to travel on various
>   modes of transport involved in a routing in order to reach a final
>   destination.
>
> One Multilateral Agreement concluded with another airline through IATA
>   results in joining a partnership of the growing network of over 350
>   participating worldwide domestic and international airlines.

My reading of that, is that there is only one MITA, and each airline/transport body signs up to the IATA MITA and becomes bound by the agreements found within the [MITA manual](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/mita.aspx).

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a free resource with a current list of members, however this [bankruptcy document](http://bankrupt.com/misc/AmAir_AssumedContracts113011.pdf) from 2011 appears to provide a list of member airlines at that time. Airlines such as KLM, Qantas, British Airways were at that time signatories of MITA.

A [couple](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/other-north-south-american-airlines/1644296-gol-no-online-checkin-brazil-airpass.html) of [posts](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage-pre-consolidation-closed-posting/994632-gol-airpass-through-aa.html) on Flyertalk discuss the airpass bought in conjunction with Hahn Air and BA with which Gol doesn't have bilateral interlining, hence the reference to the IATA MITA seems applicable.

Comment: Those posts seem to me circular! I had found them but, following the links, it seems that they are saying it can be any the 4 partner airlines or any other as long as they have a MITA with GOL.

Comment: @Itai There is one set of pricing for certain partner airlines and one set for all other MITA airlines. It seems most airlines have signed up to MITA so you can probably use just about any one with the AIRPASS2 pricing

Comment: Cool! I intend to arrive on a Star Alliance member, not sure which at the moment, but that would be great.

Comment: @Itai Also, I suspect the reason they have to be a MITA member is that that is the way the fare settlement is accomplished. Without it, there'd be no way that Gol could be paid on non-MITA (or partner) plated ticket

Answer (score 15):

Disclaimer: I work at [Flightfox](http://flightfox.com)

A [MITA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlining) (Multilateral Interline Traffic Agreement) means that separate airlines can issue flights as a part of one reservation. In practice, it means that:

1. You can buy a flight on 2 airlines as 1 reservation
2. Your bag will fly all the way to the final destination, even between different airlines (with exception when immigration authorities require you to re-check the bag when entering the country, eg. USA).

According to [ExpertFlyer](http://www.expertflyer.com), GOL has E-Ticket Interline Agreement with the following airlines:

- AirFrance
- Aerolíneas Argentinas
- Alitalia
- Copa Airlines
- Delta
- Etihad
- Iberia
- Korean Air
- KLM
- Qatar Airways
- Tap Portugal

[image: Source: ExpertFlyer.com]

Please note, that AirPass rules mention *flights operated and ticketed by any airline*. It means that an United flight marketed and sold by Copa will not work. I recommend to get in touch with GOL and confirm if the flights you want to book will qualify for AirPass.

Comment: I think those agreements are bilateral though

Comment: I think the way to make sure if they are bilateral is to check interline agreements for each of those airlines separately with ExpertFlyer and see if GOL is listed as a partner (in opposite direction)

Comment: "Bilateral" is a term almost always referring to the agreement between Governments. For example, "the Bermuda II bilateral opened Heathrow...etc, etc..."

Comment: Sorry if this sounds obvious to you but are E-Tickets MITA a subset or the same as just MITA? If the former, there must be other airlines in the ground, right?

Comment: @Itai yes, if you take a look a the screenshot I posted, there are more airlines with "Paper Ticket and Baggage Interline Agreements". I recommend to reach out to Gol to get a definitive list of airlines that fall under the AirPass

Comment: The interline agreements on expertflyer are not MITA agreements though, nor is the link to wikipedia anything to do with MITA either.